# Angular6 Service for created module

Tags: angular, angular6

If you created service `@Injectable --> providedIn should be 'root'`. How to set providedIn value for a created module. That means service only for a created module.

Root module

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {}
```

MyOwnMoudle

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: '???'   //This service only for MyOwnModule
})
export class MyService{}
```

Comment: If you have a root module and a lazyLoading module (ie. `myOwnModule`) just provide the service in the lazyLoaded module

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: Thanks for your response. @JacopoSciampi and JB Nizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject `providers` only in specific [module](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service), you can do this way :

```
import { MyModule } from './myModule.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModule   // It should not be string
})
export class MyService{}
```